# The object passed of type Class.TableViewDataSource does not derive from NSObject?

Tags: uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am getting "The object passed of type Class.TableViewDataSource does not derive from NSObject" error when I do the following I am trying to set the datasource of a UITableView.

```
    viewdidload {
        tableView.DataSource = new TableViewDataSource(al);
    }
    class TableViewDataSource : IUITableViewDataSource
        {
            public ArrayList listOfSellers
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public TableViewDataSource(ArrayList al) {
                listOfSellers = al; 
            }
            public UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
            {
                var cell = (SellerCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell("cell", indexPath);
                cell.seller.Text = (string)listOfSellers[indexPath.Row];
                return cell;
            }

            public nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableView, nint section)
            {
                return listOfSellers.Count;
            }
        }
```

Any ideas why that might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the class derives from interface, you have to implement all the method defined in its parent interface.

Here  the method in `INativeObject` , `IDisposable` is also needed to implement.

```
public class TableViewDataSource : IUITableViewDataSource
{
    public IntPtr Handle { get; }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }
}
```

However, in general we use `UITableViewDataSource` instead . It derives from `IUITableViewDataSource` , we just need to override the method inside it .

```
public class TableViewDataSource : UITableViewDataSource
{
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var cell = (SellerCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell("cell", indexPath);
        cell.seller.Text = (string)listOfSellers[indexPath.Row];
        return cell;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableView, nint section)
    {
        return listOfSellers.Count;
    }
}
```